# Unkown error while executing heavy query on Pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Pymongo .find() throwing error when find takes too long or contains a lot of documents. By wrapping everything in a try/catch and printing the exception nothing prints out.

What Im thinking is that it may be a timeout set on Mongo by default that may interrupt the query but I've tried to wrap it on the following handlers but none worked: pymongo.errors.ExecutionTimeout, pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge, pymongo.errors.PyMongoError

Note:
This works on my laptop which has 8gb RAM and 254 SSD but not on a server with 64gb RAM and 10TB RAID HDD.

This is my function:

```py
def getBacktestOrderBook(start, end):
    query = {'date': { "$gt": start , "$lt": end }}
    return list(dbMyTable.find(query))
```

Comment: Try not to convert it to a list and simply return `dbMyTable.find(query)`?

Comment: Ok so not converting it to list stops the exception but I need it to be a list, why does this work in my PC but not in another PC with more RAM?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `dbMyTable.find(query)` returns a cursor object which is a generator. You can try to do a `for i in dbMyTable.find(query): print (i)` for troubleshooting.

Comment: Never mind, solved it. I had 32-bits installed on server and 64-bits on my laptop.